# Lmer output in R: Why is the variable name changing?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

I am running an lmer function in R as follows, and I notice that the **condition** variable in the output changes from "**condition**" to "**conditionE**". In the data, condition has two values, "E" and "C". Does anyone know why this is happening or how to explain this behavior? What does this mean for the result (Estimate, -0.41434), namely is the result for the condition or for the conditionE?

```
> var7 <- lmer(grade.Post1 ~ 1 + condition + CPre5 + (1 | teacherID), data=data)
> summary(var7)
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: grade.Post1 ~ 1 + condition + CPre5 + (1 | teacherID)
   Data: data

REML criterion at convergence: 867.2

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.1345 -0.6262 -0.0416  0.6375  4.4576 

Random effects:
 Groups    Name        Variance  Std.Dev.
 teacherID (Intercept) 0.0005629 0.02372 
 Residual              2.0504858 1.43195 
Number of obs: 242, groups:  teacherID, 5

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  5.61535    0.13089   42.90
conditionE  -0.41434    0.18633   -2.22
CPre5        0.86071    0.03029   28.41

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
           (Intr) cndtnE
conditionE -0.706       
CPre5      -0.108  0.153
```

Comment: It would be interesting to know what you mean by "the result for the condition."  To which condition would you be referring: "C" or "E"?

Comment: In R, if your dataframe has a column, `stuff`, with unique values `A`, `B`, `C`. In ANOVA, R orders the factors and zeroes out the first factor (combining it's effect into the mean or intercept). The remaining factors remain untouched and names are concatenated as  column_name:factor, such as `stuffB` and `stuffC`. There will not be a `stuffA` in the output.

Comment: @whuber I meant is the estimate for the condition as a variable overall (both for E and C) or only for the E part of the condition (i.e only the data points that were in the E condition)

Answer (score 6):

To illustrate my explanation (in comments), here's an example with ANOVA example. Displaying below is the summary table (not ANOVA table) with *contrast* variable names.

```
  > fit = lm(wt ~ as.factor(cyl), data = mtcars)
  > summary(fit)

  Call:
  lm(formula = wt ~ as.factor(cyl), data = mtcars)

  Residuals:
      Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
  -0.8292 -0.4346 -0.1567  0.3229  1.4248 

  Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
  (Intercept)       2.2857     0.1899  12.037 8.41e-13 ***
  as.factor(cyl)6   0.8314     0.3045   2.730   0.0106 *  
  as.factor(cyl)8   1.7135     0.2538   6.753 2.07e-07 ***
  ---
  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

  Residual standard error: 0.6298 on 29 degrees of freedom
  Multiple R-squared:  0.6124,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.5857 
  F-statistic: 22.91 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: 1.075e-06

  > unique(mtcars$cyl)
  [1] 6 4 8
```

Note that the unique factors are `4`, `6`, `8` in that order. R moves `4`'s effect to the mean, and keeps the remaining as factors. Take note of the concatenated names in the output. The R manuals explain this somewhere, unfortunately, I don't remember where.

I believe SAS does something similar as well, except with the last factor not the first.

Faraway has a nice guide for linear regression and ANOVA. Review Ch 15.2 to get an understanding of what/why R is doing in the background with categorical variables.
ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/doc/contrib/Faraway-PRA.pdf

Comment: Thank you @Jon. So basically, what you are saying is that this is a standard thing that R does and it should be ok, namely it is not messing up my results or anything like that?

Comment: That's not an ANOVA table. And the relevant term is "treatment contrasts".

Comment: @Roland Yes, that is correct, the output is not an ANOVA table; It is summary output for a one-way ANOVA analysis. And thanks for the term.